# Access data on phone with broken screen (Samsung galaxy S5)

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, data-recovery, broken-screen

I'm trying to retrieve data from my poor dead phone. I can turn it on, but the screen doesn't work, so I'm not even sure it is at the lock screen. Anyways usually I use a software called Android file transfer to download and upload data, but it won't access the phone because it's locked. The screen doesn't work at all, any solutions?

Comment: Do you remember having the USB Debugging turned on?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think yes

Comment: Well, but we need to be sure if it is enabled. Download Samsung  drivers from the internet and also grab Minimal ADB & Fastboot. Tell ke wheb ready.

Comment: You need to check and see if you still have USB Debugging enabled

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my poor S4 with a screen lock sometime back. To remove the lock, I used the Google app Find my Device to reset the password to a keyboard typable one (you can't just remove the password through it), then after that I used a USB OTG adapter with a USB keyboard to type the password in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have USB debugging enabled on you device, [Droid@Screen](http://droid-at-screen.org/) allows seeing the screen output and also interacting.

Though it's slow but could help you out.

**Note**: You'll need the appropriate ADB drivers installed on your PC.